# Question to a proof about hitting and first return times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, stopping-times

I have a question to the following proof:
[image]

I do not understand the line

$$
\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > kr\} \leq (1-\varepsilon)\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > (k-1)r\} \tag{1.17}.
$$

I think the claim in the text is that
$$
\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} \in \{t,t+1, \ldots, t+r\}\} \geq \varepsilon.
\tag{$\star$}
$$

This would imply

$$
\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} \in \{(k-1)r,(k-1)r+1, \ldots, kr\}\} \geq \varepsilon
$$
and 
$$
\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} \notin \{(k-1)r,(k-1)r+1, \ldots, kr\}\} \leq 1 - \varepsilon
$$ 
and

$$
\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > kr\} = \textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > kr \mid \tau_{y}^{+} > (k-1)r\} \textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > (k-1)r\} \\
\leq \textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} \notin \{(k-1)r,(k-1)r+1, \ldots, kr\}\} \textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > (k-1)r\} 
$$
because of monotonicity ($\{\tau_{y}^{+} > kr \mid \tau_{y}^{+} > (k-1)r\} \subseteq \{\tau_{y}^{+} \notin \{(k-1)r,(k-1)r+1, \ldots, kr\}\}$).

If these thoughts are correct, my question reduces to the verification of $(\star)$. I think that this follows from the (strong?) Markov property, but I am not sure how to apply.

Answer (score 2):

The text is correct. Your statement (*) is not valid.

It is true that with probility $\ge \epsilon$ the chain will visit state $y$ in the interval $\{t,t+1,...,t+r\}$, but not necessarily for the first time.

So you need to condition your calculation according to $P(\tau_y^+ \lt t)$

Comment: Ok, so using that with probility $\geq \varepsilon$ the chain will visit state $y$ in the interval $\{t,t+1,...,t+r\}$ (for $t=0$), I get
$$
\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > r\}   \leq \textbf{P}_{x}\{X_1 \neq y, \ldots, X_{r} \neq y\} = 1 -  \textbf{P}_{x}\{\exists i \in\{1,\ldots,r\}\colon X_i = y\} \leq 1 - \varepsilon.
$$
Now if I could show that 
$$
\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > kr\}  \leq \textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > r\}\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > (k-1)r\}
$$
I would get the result. How is this true?

Comment: Following your hint, to condition my calculation according to $\textbf{P}\{\tau_y^+ < t\}$, I would start with 
$$
\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > kr\} = \textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > kr \mid \tau_y^+ < t\} \textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_y^+ < t\}.
$$
But for which $t$ should I do that? This does not make sense for $t=(k-1)r$.

Comment: The inequality $$\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > kr\}  \leq \textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > r\}\textbf{P}_{x}\{\tau_{y}^{+} > (k-1)r\}$$ seems to be wrong in general.